# Magnolia CMS - How to reset selected value using LinkFieldDefinition?

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I'm trying to implement **detail** application with with one form field type of LinkField. The field definition looks like below:

```
  - name: someProperty
    targetWorkspace: some-workspace
    valueProperty: name
    labelProperty: name
    appName: some-app
    path: /
    class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.LinkFieldDefinition
    identifierToPathConverter:
      class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.converter.BaseIdentifierToPathConverter
```

And the result looks like:

[image]

The problem is I cannot find a way to reset this field after the value has been chosen. Is there any additional option that enables deleting chosen value?

Comment: Hi, why do you want to reset that field in the first place? Normally, one would like to do the following: either select a new item or submit this selection.

Comment: @Ducaz035 the scenario is: 1) user picks a value and saves the form 2) after some time user wants to pick empty value and save the form with no value selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not meaningfully possible but a potential workaround is to remove the "pathToLinkedItem" and save the dialogue. Indeed, this overrides the existing value.

Cheers,

Hope That helps,

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to create a new **LinkFieldDefinition** with your custom **LinkField** and **LinkFieldFactory**.

1. You will need to add a new vaadin component(reset button) in **LinkField**
2. After you create the button attach click listener to that button where you will reset the value of the text field **LinkFieldFactory**.

info.magnolia.ui.form.field.factory.LinkFieldFactory

info.magnolia.ui.field.LinkFieldDefinition

info.magnolia.ui.form.field.LinkField